# Function to produce a vector field with two focal areas: one in the top right and one in the bottom left quadrant.

Tags: functions, vectors, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I'm trying to make a ***conceptual*** visualization of a system with two stable areas in a $2$-dimensional possibility space.  To do this I want to produce a vector field showing the direction the system will tend to evolve towards from any given point in possibility space. What I want to end up with is something like this:

> [image]

All the vectors point towards either the center of the bottom left hand quadrant or the top right hand quadrant. I can make a nice visualization of a vector function using $R$, but I need a mathematical function that describes the vector field that I want. Is there a simple function that will produce such a vector field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone is wondering, an answer is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eply.gif)

and the working R script is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383286/using-map-within-mutate-to-iterate-over-two-dataframes).